# Is there any possible way to prevent the mirror to reflect some custom objects?

Tags: rendering, light, emission

So, I had a little problem here; I made the cube invisible but still glowing around the environment. And the problem is I want to prevent the cube to reflect on the mirror. Is there any possible way to prevent the mirror to reflect some custom objects? Or is there any better solution? Thanks! [image]

Comment: related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/192907/rendering-a-fake-mirror/192911#192911

Comment: Nevermind, I've figured it out. Just turn of "camera" and "glossy" at the ray view options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use this setting (Cycles only):

[image]

We want to keep what is diffuse and not singular (or glossy).