# How to hide certain objects in reflection in Eevee

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

[image]

Hello, I want to make the kettlebell shiny but without those reflections of other objects. Is there a way to make certain objects not visible in the reflection in Eevee?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rendering a fake mirror](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/192907/rendering-a-fake-mirror) you'll need a light probe also

Answer (score 0):

This link should help describe what you are looking for but it shows an older version of blender.

[https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44649/how-to-get-rid-of-an-objects-reflection#:~:text=In%20the%20properties%20window%20go,disable%20Ray%20Visibility%20for%20glossy](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44649/how-to-get-rid-of-an-objects-reflection#:%7E:text=In%20the%20properties%20window%20go,disable%20Ray%20Visibility%20for%20glossy).

The image below shows where to find the these settings in Blender 2.9.

If you select the object you don't want to reflect, in your case the pan and the egg, then toggle the "Glossy" option under "Ray Visibility" in the "Visibility" settings in the objects properties.

[image: Ray Visability]

[image: No reflection]

Comment: I updated my blender version to 2.9 but I still don't have the option for Ray Visibility.. Maybe it's because I'm using Eevee instead of Cycles? How do I achieve the same effect in Eevee?